# How to play 360 video on Android Cardboard SDK

Tags: android, google-cardboard, google-vr

I wanted to play 360 videos on Google's Cardboard Latest SDK but I don't know how to play using it as currently proper documentation is not available.

Almost all demo and documentation are for Google GVR SDK and this SDK is deprecated.

documentation for cardboard that i referred is are below

https://developers.google.com/cardboard/develop/c/quickstart

https://github.com/googlevr/cardboard

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Same here bro, If you find any solution plz update here